Mapping from luminance (Candela / m²) to perceived brightness
As I understand it luminance (measured in Candela / m²) is a physical measure for the brightness perceived by the human eye. So the unit Candela already takes into account the biological response function of our retina -- it doesn't just measure total emitted light energy. Still, Candela / m² is not exactly proprtional to perceived (subjective) brightness + this discrepancy depends on the frequency spectrum of the presented light. And obviously this discrepancy will vary with different human observers.
[Edit: And, as pointed out by Steven Kersting, subjective brightness is surely not proportional to Candela, but rather scales logarithmically due to Weber–Fechner].
With this info in mind, my question is as follows. I am interested in the perceived brightness of an average (or "standard") observer for a set of colors presented on a screen (defined as RGB triplets 0..255). I do have the luminance (Candela / m²) measurements for these colors for the screen of interest. Is it possible to estimate perceived brightness with this info for a standard observer (*)?
I also have the luminance measurements for each channel alone, i.e. when the RGP triplet was (50, 100, 70), I have the channel-wise luminance measurements for (50, 0, 0), (0, 100, 0) and (0, 0, 70). Not sure this is of help though.
Unfortunately, I don't have access to this screen anymore and thus can't do experiments.
(* standard observer referring to standardized observers as e.g. defined by the International Commission on Illumination, CIE:
https://cie.co.at/publications/colorimetry-part-1-cie-standard-colorimetric-observers)

Could you explain the photographic problem you're trying to solve here?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about photography.

The candela does not take into consideration the human response curve to brightness (perceived brightness). The candela scale is linear measured in lumens; whereas the human response is logarithmic. The candela does however take into account human response being stronger to certain wavelengths of light.

@StevenKersting Thanks, this is very helpful.

@RomeoNinov Most questions I found that were conceptually close to mine were in the Photography section. I was considering the Physics StackExchange, but I was worried that there is little experience about the subjective/behavioral effects of brightness perception. Still, I can understand if this question is considered a non-fit for the Photography StackExchange.

I don't think you could determine perceived brightness due to the adaptive nature of the human eye (pupil dilation, rhodopsin levels)... it's much like auto aperture or auto ISO for a camera; the sensed exposure remains the same. You could only determine it relative to something else; and that is logarithmic, like "stops" are for a camera..

Did you check the Color FAQ?

@StevenKersting True that, but perceived brightness can still be determined experimentally in a way that allows for a relative comparison between different levels for hue, saturation, lightness.

@Grimaldi, are you referring to this ressource: https://www.poynton.ca/ColorFAQ.html ? I'll check it out.

Does this [so] Q/A answer your question? Formula to determine perceived brightness of RGB color

@scottbb, thanks. It doesn't answer my question unfortunately, because perceived brightness additionally depends on the screen that presents the RGB values (unless the screen was properly calibrated, which it wasn't in my case).
